# Cannot use sudo in jenkins' `execute shell` build step

Tags: docker, jenkins, electron, devops, fakeroot

I'm trying to use `electron-installer-debian` in Jenkins (version 2.346.2) dashboard. But it has a `fakeroot` dependency. Trying to install `fakeroot` using `apt-get install fakeroot` and error says 'permission denied'. If I use `sudo apt-get install fakeroot`, error says `command: sudo : not found`. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: If you have direct access to the Jenkins machine, try installing it from there instead of from within Jenkins.

Comment: @MB i installed it on an EC2 instance of AWS. I can use sudo there, just not on the Jenkins execute shell build step. thanks btw